# Getting element by undefined tag name

Tags: python, xml-parsing, minidom

I'm parsing an xml document in Python using minidom.

I have an element:

```
<informationRequirement>
  <requiredDecision href="id"/>
</informationRequirement>
```

The only thing I need is value of href in subelement but its tag name can be different (for example *requiredKnowledge* instead of *requiredDecision*; it always shall begin with *required*).
If the tag was always the same I would use something like:

```
element.getElementsByTagName('requiredDecision')[0].attributes['href'].value
```

But that's not the case. What can be substitute of this knowing that tag name varies?

(there will be always **one** subelement)

Comment: What if you have both `requiredKnowledge` and `requiredDecision` with different `href` values?

Comment: It would be a problem but it's not possible. There can be only one subelement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always guaranteed to have one subelement, just grab that element:

```
element.childNodes[0].attributes['href'].value
```

However, this is brittle.  A (perhaps) better approach could be:

```
hrefs = []
for child in element.childNodes:
  if child.tagName.startswith('required'):
    hrefs.append(child.attributes['href'].value)
```

Comment: `for element in xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('informationRequirement'):
    print(element.getElementsByTagName('requiredDecision')[0].attributes['href'].value)
    print(element.childNodes[0].attributes['href'].value)`

Comment: First print outputs correctly, second one does nothing. Sorry for three comments, I don't know yet how to edit them.